# Unable to reduce TIME_WAIT

Tags: tcp, time-wait

I'm attempting to reduce the amount of time a connection is in the TIME_WAIT state by setting tcp_fin_timeout detailed [here](http://www.linuxbrigade.com/reduce-time_wait-socket-connections/):

```
root:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
```

However, this setting does not appear to affect anything.  When I look at the netstat of the machine, the connections still wait the default 60s:

```
root:~# watch netstat -nato
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34185         127.0.0.1:11209         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.14/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34190         127.0.0.1:11209         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.14/0/0)
```

Is there something I'm missing?  The machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Answer (score 7):

Your link is urban myth. The actual function of `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` is [as follows](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp):

> This specifies how many seconds to wait for a final FIN packet before the socket is forcibly closed. This is strictly a violation of the TCP specification, but required to prevent denial-of-service attacks. In Linux 2.2, the default value was 180.

This doesn't have anything to do with TIME_WAIT. It establishes a timeout for a socket in FIN_WAIT_1, after which the connection is reset (which bypasses TIME_WAIT altogether). This is a DOS measure, as stated, and should never arise in a correctly written client-server application. You don't want to set it so low that ordinary connections are reset: you will lose data. You don't want to fiddle with it at all, actually.

The correct way to reduce TIME_WAIT states is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065889/207421).

Comment: How does one find the value for TIME_WAIT that's currently being used? I couldn't find the info on the linked answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is 2*MSL. which is either 2 or 4 minutes, I foget which. Some OS's may provide a way to tune it, but doing so is not the answer. Reversing who gets into the state is the answer.